# VBA: Display "NA" in cell on error

Tags: vba, excel

With below code I am calculating the RSS. It does however happen that the Y range does not actually contain values. I have surpassed the error (Run-time error '1004') that displays when there aren't any values with 'on error goto next' but then it just 'copies' the same value as the previous one in the destination cell when there wouldn't actually be any.

Is there a way to display "NA" in stead of the previous value in the destination cell where the RSS cannot be calculated due to a lack of Y values?

Thank you in advance

```
Private Sub Regr(strWksData As String, WsTools As Worksheet, strWksFF3 As String, strWksResult As String)

Dim NoOfRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim sData As Worksheet
Dim sFF3 As Worksheet
Dim sResult As Worksheet

Dim rX1 As Range

Dim rY1 As Range


'General
Set sData = Sheets("Return")
Set sFF3 = Sheets("FF-3")
Set sResult = Sheets("Result")

'Set X ranges
Set rX1 = sFF3.Range("C2:E21")

'Set Y ranges

Set rY1 = sData.Range("F2:F21")

'Loop through columns
'Provide statistic
On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
For i = 0 To 5
vStat1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(rY1.Offset(0, i), rX1, True, True)
sResult.Range("F2").Offset(0, i).Value = vStat1(5, 2)
NoOfRow = rY1.Rows.Count
WsTools.Range("B2").Value = NoOfRow
Next i


ErrorHandling:

Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0
MsgBox ("RSS Done")


End Sub
```

Comment: `vStat1 = "na"`  or you can look at raising the error in excel `cverr(xlerrna)`

Comment: Could you simply set `vStat1(5,2) = "NA"` before invoking `LinEst` - therefore if `LinEst` crashes you will have the value you set rather than the previous value calculated.  You will need to actually `Dim` the variable correctly for that to work though.  (P.S.  Your error handling is all wrong.)

Comment: Thank you both for your answer!  `vStat1 = "na"` did the trick. The error handling was a piece I found online that I tried to use to add a value in the cell, which obviously failed. Thank you again!

Comment: To expand on Yowe3K's answer, your error handling shouldn't simply "Resume Next" when encountering an error. This is a very dangerous practice since you can get unexpected results. There are some instances where it makes sense, but generally it is best to handle the error. One way to overcome this in your code would be to use a boolean value that gets set to false each loop. On error goto errorhandler which sets it true then 'Resume'. Add an if block that only runs the if when bool = false, else it writes "NA'.

Comment: @BrandonBarney - Also, the "Resume Next" which will be performed when no error has occurred will generate an error, which will cause it to go to the error handler and execute "Resume Next" again (this time with an error in existence) and then will finally go to `On Error GoTo 0`.  It will "work", but is definitely not the right way to do things.

Comment: @YowE3K I totally missed that he didnt have an exit there. Good catch! Definitely agree that it will 'work' but will cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are writing the results directly to the worksheet, just take advantage of the different error reporting behavior of `Application.LinEst` v. `Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst`.

When you call the fully qualified `WorksheetFunction`, any error raised in the called function is thrown as a run-time error:

`Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum("a", "b")      '<--runtime error 1004`

When you use the extensible interface on `Application`, any error raised in the called function is returned wrapped in a `Variant`:

`Debug.Print Application.Sum("a", "b")           '<--Prints Error 2015 (#VALUE!)`

If you need to test to see whether or not it's an error, you can use the `IsError` function:

```
Dim v As Variant
v = Application.Sum("a", "b")
Debug.Print IsError(v)  '<-- True
```

In your case, you can just write the error value directly to the cell:

```
For i = 0 To 5
    Dim result As Variant
    result = Application.LinEst(rY1.Offset(0, i), rX1, True, True)
    'Don't attempt to use the indexer on an error.
    If IsError(result) Then
        sResult.Range("F2").Offset(0, i).Value = result
    Else
        sResult.Range("F2").Offset(0, i).Value = result(5, 2)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Grrrr - I looked to see whether `Application.LinEst` existed - but Intellisense failed again.  I have to learn not to trust it.

Comment: @YowE3K - FWIW, I'm pretty sure that everything available in the `WorksheetFunction` interface is available via the extended interface.  They're just late bound.

Comment: This works but when I expand it to multiple rows (see my edited answer) then it does not anymore. Any help on that?

Comment: @AxRo - The exact same concept works.  Look at the comment in the code above - `'Don't attempt to use the indexer on an error.`

Comment: @Comintern So how would I expand my code for more rows such as in the other answer? Do you have any thoughts as to why the lay out just won't work?

Comment: @AxRo - Like I pointed out above and mentioned in the answer itself, you need to add the test `If IsError(vStat1)`.  When you attempt to use an error like an array `vStat1(5, 2)`, you're going to get a run-time error.  I'm not sure how much more clearly I can explain that.

Comment: I solved the problem. I forgot to re-adjust my ranges. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @AxRo - It might be easier for us if you include in the question the values that you have in `Sheets("FF-3").Range("C21:E64")`, `Sheets("Return").Range("F2:F21")` and `Worksheets(strWksData).Range("G22:G64")` - then we can try and run the code and see what is happening.

Comment: @Comintern and YowE3K thank you both very much for your help and my apologies for the troubles. The code works now after correcting my ranges